# Is TFS 11 Beta website a "MVC Application"?

Tags: model-view-controller

TFS 11 Beta websites doesn't contain any ViewState and it seems like a "MVC Applicatione". Is it implemented using "MVC"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah it is they rewrote it all in MVC for v11

Watch this if youre interested, they talk about it
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-793T

Comment: yeah ild say watch this space as if they went to those lengths they probably have future plans for the TFS web suite